# System error when opening Wav File passed as an argument to Fastapi endpoint

Tags: python, path, wav, fastapi

As the title states I am trying to pass a path of a wav file to a FastAPI endpoint

The purpose of this program is to convert speech to text using speechbrain, this is a portion of my code

```
@app.get("/{audio_path:path}")
async def root(audio_path: str):
    instructions..
```

The error I get :

```
RuntimeError: Error opening 'favicon.ico': System error.
```

I tried adding this portion of code :

```
@app.get('/favicon.ico', include_in_schema=False)
def favicon():
    return FileResponse(favicon_path)
```

This is the error I get :

```
OSError: [WinError 1921] The name of the file cannot be resolved by the system: 'favicon.ico'
```

the wav file name is : test.wav and it is stored in the project directory, I tried the following paths

```
/test.wav
/D://Projects/speech_Recognizer/test.wav
```

I had no previous experience with FastAPI so I am wondering if there is anything I've ignored in setting up my api like setting a favicon or something similar..

Comment: Your browser will attempt to request `/favicon.ico` when you open a URL directly in your browser - this is the icon displayed on the tab itself to indicate which site you have open. You can safely ignore this if you don't want to display an icon, and instead raise an `HTTPException` with `status_code=404` to indicate file not found.

Comment: Thank you for your response @MatsLindh , here is how I tried to implement HTTPException 

@app.get('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail='Favicon.ico not found')

Comment: @MatsLindh still not working though so could it be a path related problem ? 
I mean if the wav file is in my project directory than my endpoint will be something like this (127.0.0.1:8000/test.wav) right ?

Comment: That would depend on what your code looks like. Start by determining what `audio_path` is and what your current working directory is. Make sure that you're not suddenly making it possible for anyone to download any file from your project by giving the file name (including git repository information, etc.). I'd strongly recommend using a static file handler with a subdirectory instead unless you have full control over what you're doing (.. and using a subdirectory for file storage would be a good idea regardless).